# Question is of Probability. I am mising some basics here.

Tags: probability

A random variable $X$ assumes the values $-3, -2, -1,0, 1 , 2 , 3$ such that
$\mathbb{P}(X = -3)= \mathbb{P}(X= -2)= \mathbb{P}(X= -1)$,
$\mathbb{P}(X= 1)= \mathbb{P}(X= 2)= \mathbb{P}(X= 3)$,
and $\mathbb{P}(X= 0) = \mathbb{P}(X > 0) = \mathbb{P}( X < 0)$.

Obtain the probability mass function of $X$ and its distribution function, and find
further the probability mass function of $Y = 2X^2 + 3X + 4$.

Comment: Start with the probability that x equals zero. What do you get here?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the sum of the probabilities of each individual outcome must equal $1$. 
 That is for this specific scenario, we have: $$Pr(X=-3)+Pr(X=-2)+Pr(X=-1)+Pr(X=0)+Pr(X=1)+Pr(X=2)+Pr(X=3)=1$$

Next, recall that the probability of an event is equal to the sum of the probabilities of the outcomes within that event.  That is for this specific scenario, we have:

$$Pr(X>0)=Pr(X=1)+Pr(X=2)+Pr(X=3)$$ and similarly so for $Pr(X<0)$

We are told that $Pr(X=0)=Pr(X>0)=Pr(X<0)$.  This implies that $Pr(X=0)=\underline{~~~~~~~~}$

> $Pr(X=0)=\frac{1}{3}$

Which further implies what $Pr(X>0)$ is equal to.  Then from the problem statement, we are told that $Pr(X=1)=Pr(X=2)=Pr(X=3)$ so this tells us that $Pr(X=1)=\underline{~~~~~~}$

> $Pr(X=1)=\frac{1}{9}$

Similarly so for all others.  With all of this information, we can now fully describe $X$'s pdf and pmf.

As for talking about $Y=2X^2+3X+4$, we have $Pr(Y=k)$ is equal to the sum of the probabilities of $Pr(X=x)$ where $x$ ranges over all values such that $2x^2+3x+4=k$.  It may help to organize your thoughts with a table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}X&2X^2+3X+4\\\hline -3&13\\-2&6\\-1&3\\0&4\\1&9\\2&18\\3&31\end{array}$$

For our specific scenario then, we see that $Pr(Y=13)$ for instance is equal to $Pr(X=-3)$ and so on...  Had there been multiple occurrences of the same value on the right hand side, then we might have needed to add multiple together.  For instance, if we were interested in the random variable $Z=X^2$, we would have $Pr(Z=4)=Pr(X=2)+Pr(X=-2)$

All that remains is to organize the final results and present the final answers.